# Make cshtml "table" composed by <divs> sortable

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, razor

I am not very used to front end programming, so excuse me if it is a pretty noobish question.

I have a table (not really an Html , but a table composed by divs) with  this format:

```
<!--List of existing Columns -->
<div class="MyTable-list-container">
    <div class="MyTable-table-header">
        <div class="span2 MyTable-table-header-label">@ColumL.ID_Column_Label</div>
        <div class="span2 MyTable-table-header-label">@ColumL.Name_Column_Label</div>
        <div class="span2 MyTable-table-header-label">@ColumL.Address_Column_Label</div>
        <div class="span2 MyTable-table-header-label">@ColumL.MAC_Column_Label</div>
        <div class="span2 MyTable-table-header-label">@ColumL.Device_Column_Label</div>
    </div>
    <div id="MyTable-table-container" class="MyTable-table-scroll">
        <!-- ko foreach: ColumLsList -->
        <div class="MyTable-table-row" data-bind="attr: { id: 'MyTable' + Name() + '_' + BoardId() }">
            <span class="span2 MyTable-content" data-bind="text: Id"></span>
            <span class="span2 MyTable-content" data-bind="text: Name"></span>
            <span class="span2 MyTable-content" data-bind="text: Address"></span>
            <span class="span2 MyTable-content" data-bind="text: Mac"></span>
            <span class="span2 MyTable-content" data-bind="text: device "></span>

            <button class="span1 btn-link" data-bind="click: $parent.setOnEditionMode">
                <i class="icon-pencil"></i> @Common.Edition_Title
            </button>
            <button class="span1 btn-link" data-bind="click: $parent.askDeleteConfirmation">
                <i class="icon-trash"></i>@Common.Remove
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Which will produce the next output:

[image]

This is what CSS looks like, in case it helps:

```
#MyTable-container {
  height: 95%;
}
#MyTable-container .row-fluid .span2 {
  width: 14%;
}
#MyTable-container select,
#MyTable-container input[type="text"] {
  max-width: 180px;
}
#MyTable-container .error {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
#MyTable-container .MyTable-list-container {
  height: 75%;
}
#MyTable-container .MyTable-table-header {
  color: #F0F1F5;
  border: 1px;
  background-color: #263249;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  height: 5%;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}
#MyTable-container .MyTable-table-header-label {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#MyTable-container .MyTable-table-scroll {
  height: 98%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #D8DBE7;
}
#MyTable-container .apply-filter-button {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
#MyTable-container .MyTable-content {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#MyTable-container .MyTable-table-row {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}
```

I would like to make table sortable by columns, so that rows get sorted asc/desc by the column i clicked. How can i achieve this?

Comment: you need to sort the data

Comment: Could that be more specific please?

Comment: Looking at the line:`<!-- ko foreach: ColumLsList -->` you're using knockout.js to create the table using the values in the variable **ColumLsList**, so you need to sort the data inside **ColumLsList** when OnCLick the column header (or what ever you want to be clicked to sort)

Comment: So for each column header it would be something like **<div class="span2 MyTable-table-header-label" data-bind="click: sortColumn">@ColumL.ID_Column_Label</div>** and in functions add something like:   **var // Properties
        ColumLsList = ko.observableArray(), sortColumn = function () {
            ColumLsList.sort(function (left, right) {
                return left.name == right.name ? 0 : (left.name < right.name ? -1 : 1)
            });
        },** but i can not make it work

Comment: Perhaps something like this would work?  **div class="span2 MyTable-table-header-label" data-bind="sort: { arr:ColumLsList, prop: 'Name'}">@ColumL.ID_Column_Label</div>**  but adding something for click before sort